# Jersey does not serialize objects correctly

Tags: jersey

i have some issues with serializing JSON into Java object. I try to retrieve object from API and then store it into Java object, but object have always default initialized values and not this which I have requested from server. My client API call looks like:

```
JerseyClient client = new JerseyClientBuilder().build();

        JerseyWebTarget target = client.register(new JacksonFeature()).target("http://localhost:8080/service");
        private Citizien c = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(Citizien.class);

        System.out.println("ECHO : " + c.toString());
```

I'm using Jackson 1.9.11 to serialize JSON to Java objects and notating class Citizien with @XMLRootElements and variables with @XMLElement. Api just inserts some random data and return object to client.

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue, because I don't know any solution yet.

Regards,
Dahakka

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do the resource class / citizen class look like? What do you mean by random data (can we see the JSON)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have those lines of code

```
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
webAppContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
```

Or if you work w/ web.xml to set the corresponded configuration item

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foo.bar</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>\
...
```

Comment: hm... well I'm new to this things and I don't really know yet how does mapping works. I would be very happy if you could give me a little more info about configuration, because it does not work for me when I try to add pojo mapping to my web.xml. Also I am using jersey 2.4 and not 1.x. Thank you for your help!